# Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found

Tags: pdo, php

i'm very confused about this

```
Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/itstec2/public_html/pard_config/class/Config.php on line 13
```

this is my Config.php

```
<?php

$dbhost=null;
$dbname=null;
$dbuser=null;
$dbpass=null;

$file = __DIR__ ."/config.json";

$array = file_get_contents($file);
$dbConfig=json_decode($array);

$pardConfig=new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbConfig[0].';'.'dbname='.$dbConfig[1],$dbConfig[2],$dbConfig[3]);

?>
```

Config.php file is working with all other includes.but it's not working with the domain. It has that fatal error .why is that ?

[My Domain](http://itstechnews.info/)

Comment: Is this really PHP 5.3?

Comment: Is `PDO` extension is enabled?

Comment: PDO extension not available or not enabled.

Comment: In my root i have 14 directories .I'm including my database files for others.it's all working.but it's not working when i added the root index.php file.

Comment: @DevZer0 see my new comment

Comment: @YogeshSuthar see my new comment

Comment: can you provide us with a output of `phpinfo`

Comment: http://itstechnews.info/pard_admin/ my admin directory.use admin for both.it all over working

Comment: @DevZer0 http://itstechnews.info/

Comment: according to your phpinfo PDO is not enabled

Comment: @GeraldSchneider but it is there in other files http://itstechnews.info/pard_config/class/Config.php

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how this happened ? same domain different files?

Comment: This directory uses a different php.ini (`/usr/local/lib/php.ini` vs `/home/itstec2/public_html/php.ini`, see "loaded configuration file")

Comment: I was added a empty php.ini to the root.now i removed it.Thanks @GeraldSchneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the output of your `phpinfo()` function to the other directories, where it is working you'll notice that the PDO object is indeed not loaded and that it is using a different `php.ini` in the directory where it is not working. On the working parts PHP is using `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` while it is using `/home/itstec2/public_html/php.ini` in the directory where it isn't working.

Some providers allow you to use different PHP configurations for different parts within the web root. If you use an extra ini file for a specific directory you have to make sure that you have all necessary settings in there.